# Ember JS :: Uncaught TypeError: Object App.Router has no method 'map'

Tags: ember.js

I am getting uncaught error when using map() method on router. Any ideas ??

```
App.Router.map(function(match) {
        match('/').to('index');
        match('/models').to('models');
    });
```

Error:: 
Ember JS :: Uncaught TypeError: Object App.Router has no method 'map'

Ember Version : 
http://cloud.github.com/downloads/emberjs/ember.js/ember-latest.js

Comment: which version of Ember you are using?

Comment: i am using ember-1.0.0-pre.2.js

Comment: `Router.map` is something related to new router. Not in 1.0.0-pre.2.

Comment: i see , any idea how can i get latest build for ember.js ? Cant find a link on ember site.

Comment: i have tried with http://cloud.github.com/downloads/emberjs/ember.js/ember-latest.js, but still the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit tricky to find the upadate on the official github. You can get a copy of it here though:

https://github.com/sh4n3d4v15/ember-todos/blob/master/app/scripts/vendor/ember.js

Comment: Thanks Shane, this has fixed the issue.